# Prove that the polynomial $x^3+7x+3$ and $x^3+7x+4$ are irreducible over $\Bbb Q.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I am a beginner in field extension theory. I need to prove that the polynomials $x^3+7x+3$ and $x^3+7x+4$ are irreducible over $\Bbb Q.$ The only thing that I have learnt in relation to this is Eisenstein's criterion. But I just can't find a suitable prime $p$. Since Eisenstein also works by substitution, I have also tried with replacing $x$ by $x\pm1,x\pm2,x\pm3$. Still that does not work. So I really don't know how to do this then. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: A polynomial of degree $3$ is irreducible if and only if it has no roots.

Comment: @Crostul no RATIONAL roots

Comment: You can also prove the irreducibility of $x^3+7x+3$ by proving that it is irreducible in the field $\mathbb Z_2$ and for $x^3+7x+4$, you can use the field $\mathbb Z_5$. But this would require more effort.

Comment: Eisenstein is a useful criterion, but rarely sufficient to prove irreduciblity. The reduction method (if a polynomial is irreducible over a field $\mathbb Z_p$, it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ as well) is a better tool, but can require much effort. Moreover the reduction method fails if it turns out that the polynomial is reducible over a field $\mathbb Z_p$

Comment: Eisenstein *is* sufficient – but not necessary.

Comment: @Bernard My formulation is very unlucky, the Eisenstein criterion is sufficient. What I mean is that Eisenstein can rarely be actually applied.

Comment: There are other criteria as well, for example first polynomial is irreducible by Cohn's irreducibility criterion since $f(8)=571$ is a prime. Of course in this case it is an overkill since rational roots theorem does the trick, but in higher degrees it is useful. Suggest you look also at Perron's criterion, Newton polygons and Murty's criterion.

Answer (score 3):

If the leading coefficient is $1$ and the degree of the polynomial is less than $4$ (our situation), it is sufficient to prove that the polynomial has no rational root.

The only possible rational roots are the divisors (also the negative ones!) of the constant coefficient in this case.

Comment: To prove irreducibility the leading coeffcient need not be $1$, but the search for possible rational roots is much easier in this case.

Comment: If the constant coefficient is zero the polynomial is trivially *reducible*

Comment: Is it true in the field $F[x]$ for any fielf $F$? @Peter

Comment: @J.Doe  In the case of an arbitary field, if the degree is less than $4$ , it is still sufficient to show that the polynomial has no root in the field. But this can be much more difficult because the rational root theorem does not apply anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Start from definition. If $f$ is not irreducible, then $f=gh$ for some non-invertible polynomials $g,h$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is integral domain, $\deg f = \deg g + \deg h$. Since $\deg f = 3$, we conclude that one of $g,h$ has degree $1$ (why??). But, that means that $f(X) = (X-\alpha)(X^2+aX+b)$, which means that $f$ has rational root $\alpha$. Can you show that having rational root is necessary condition as well?

Thus, you only have to check if $f$ has rational roots or not. Use [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Let me do the first polynomial. Call it $f(x)$. Note that $f'(x) = 3x^2+7$. As this derivative is always positive it follows that $f(x)$ is a monotonically increasing function throughout the real line, hence it is a on=one function. Now $f(-1)=-5$ and $f(0)=+3$, and so the unique real root is in between $-1$ and $0$. If we show that this real root is irrational, irreducibility of $f(x)$ will follow.

Write such a rational root as $-a/b$ with $a,b$ positive integers that are coprime with $a<b$.

From $f(-a/b)=0$ it follows that  $\displaystyle \frac{a^3}{b^3} +\frac{7a}b=3$. This implies that $a^3=b(3b^2-7ab)$. As rhs is a multiple of $b$ we forces to conclude that $a$ is also a multiple of $b$. That means $a/b$ is an integer. But our root is in between $-1$ and $0$. This contradiction proves that there are no rational roots.